How do I use crosstab function in DBT model
I have table with records:
CREATE TABLE dwh_dds.sales (
    region TEXT,
    product TEXT,
    sales_amount NUMERIC
) DISTRIBUTED  randomly;

INSERT INTO dwh_dds.sales (region, product, sales_amount) VALUES
('North', 'product_a', 100),
('North', 'product_b', 150),
('South', 'product_a', 200),
('South', 'product_b', 250);

When i use crosstab function and table from greerplum base (dwh_dds.sales) i have error when run dbt model:
function cannot execute on a QE slice because it accesses relation "dwh_dds.sales"  (seg22 slice1 192.168.111.195:6006 pid=1403063)
CONTEXT:  SQL statement " select * from dwh_dds.sales order by region "
-- dbt model:
WITH 
crosstab_query AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM crosstab(
        $$select * from dwh_dds.sales order by region$$,
         $$select * from (select 'product_a'::text p union select 'product_b'::text) s order by p$$
    ) AS ct (
        region TEXT,
        product_a NUMERIC,
        product_b NUMERIC
        -- Добавьте больше продуктов по необходимости
    )
)
SELECT * FROM crosstab_query

When i don't use table, rows formed in query, I don't have error, dbt understand crosstab construction, model compiled successfully
WITH 
crosstab_query AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM crosstab(
        $$ select * from (
        SELECT 'a'::text region, 'product_a'::text product, 100::NUMERIC sales_amount
        union all
          SELECT 'b'::text region, 'product_b'::text product, 200::NUMERIC sales_amount) s
        ORDER BY 1$$,
         $$select * from (select 'product_a'::text p union select 'product_b'::text) s order by p$$
    ) AS ct (
        region TEXT,
        product_a NUMERIC,
        product_b NUMERIC
        -- Добавьте больше продуктов по необходимости
    )
)
SELECT * FROM crosstab_query

How to solve error "function cannot execute on a QE slice because it accesses relation "dwh_dds.sales"  (seg22 slice1 192.168.111.195:6006 pid=1403063)" ?
How to change dbt model?
